# Plot multiple tables in a single plot

Tags: r, plot

I have 11 time series which include a temperature column. In other words there are 11 tables which should be presented in a single plot with different lines in color or line type.

```
  t1      t2      t3      t4      t5      t6      t7       t8     t9      t10      t11
 4.14    4.12    4.09    4.07    4.14    4.14    4.12    4.09    4.07    5.70    42.67 
 4.01    3.99    3.97    3.94    4.01    4.01    3.99    3.97    3.94    4.14    39.98 
 3.89    3.86    3.84    3.82    3.89    3.89    3.86    3.84    3.82    4.01    38.73 
 3.77    3.74    3.72    3.69    3.77    3.77    3.74    3.72    3.69    3.89    37.50 
 3.64    3.62    3.59    3.57    3.64    3.64    3.62    3.59    3.57    3.77    36.25 
  3.52   3.50    3.48    3.45    3.52    3.52    3.50    3.48    3.45    3.64    35.07 
  3.40   3.38    3.35    3.33    3.40    3.40    3.38    3.35    3.33    3.52    33.86 
  3.27   3.24    3.22    3.19    3.27    3.27    3.24    3.22    3.19    3.40    32.52 
  3.13   3.10    3.07    3.05    3.13    3.13    3.10    3.07    3.05    3.27    31.11 
  2.99   2.96    2.94    2.91    2.99    2.99    2.96    2.94    2.91    3.13    29.73 
  2.85   2.81    2.78    2.75    2.85    2.85    2.81    2.78    2.75    2.99    28.23 
  2.69   2.66    2.63    2.59    2.69    2.69    2.66    2.63    2.59    2.85    26.69 
  2.53   2.49    2.46    2.42    2.53    2.53    2.49    2.46    2.42    2.69    25.01 
  2.36   2.33    2.29    2.26    2.36    2.36    2.33    2.29    2.26    2.53    23.36 
  2.19   2.16    2.13    2.10    2.19    2.19    2.16    2.13    2.10    2.36    21.74 
  2.05   2.02    1.98    1.95    2.05    2.05    2.02    1.98    1.95    2.19    20.24
```

Comment: Have you   read `?plot, ?lines, ?matplot` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, I have reviewed them. The problem is that the X axis should be the same for all the tables (number of record). In other words if we consider that each table has a plot, i wanted to present all the plots of the tables in a single plot.

Comment: All the answers provided so far are variations of what `matplot` does. If your N-th column has the date values, then `matplot(data[,N],data[,-N],type='l') will give you exactly what you've asked for.

Answer (score 2):

One option is :

1. use melt to reshape data
2. ggplot2 to plot the melten data

   ```
    dat$date <- seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'),as.Date('2011-01-31'),
    length.out=dim(dat)[1])
    library(reshape2)
    dat.m <- melt(dat,id='date')
    library(ggplot2)
    qplot(data=subset(dat.m),x= date, y=value,color=variable, geom='line')
   ```

[image]

I remove the t11 variable from dataset and replot

```
     qplot(data=subset(dat.m, variable != 't11'),x= date, y=value,
        color=variable, geom='line')
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot understand how 11 separate tables are added to a single plot.